# Rails 4: How to use module from lib in initializer file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, include, initializer

I use rails 4.1. I created a module in lib/ folder in Rails: lib/corelib.rb but when I try to use it in my custom initializer file config/initializers/load_data.rb with

```
include Corelib
```

it gives me an error:

```
.../config/initializers/load_data.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Corelib (NameError)
```

How do I use my module from lib/ folder in my initializer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently I've forgotten to add require before include:

```
require 'corelib'
include Corelib
```

on top of the file in load_data.rb fixes the issue.